# How do I integrate third party APIs with Shopify to find and create products?

Tags: api, web-services, shopify, shopify-app

I have created a Shopify Store which needs to contact another outside web service to send a query and then build the products based on the query response data.

Is it possible to do with Shopify?
If yes, then how should I go about implementing it?

I have tried looking into the docs but it seems like the only option is to connect with Admin API to add products. However, I don't want to store product data but instead rely on the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do want to use Admin API calls. The reason is simple. They let you create products in Shopify, in bulk. Why fight the power! Using the Admin API has nothing to do with storing products, not sure why you're afraid.

So you get your product info from wherever, format it into Shopify-compatible data, inform Shopify of your data, and sit back and relax. The bulk building is really quite simple for a pattern. You can also build yourself a CSV to import where you also format the data to be compatible with Shopify. So there are two options for you right there.

Comment: Hello @David, appreciate your response. I am worried because there are tens of thousands of products (calling each would be very expensive) and would need to keep the products up to date as well. If I store the products then I would have to run a cron job to update products manually.